# Databricks secrets token expires

Tags: python, token, databricks

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect#overview) and managed to get my notebook running in the Visual Studio. In the python program I have dbutils.secrets.get statement to read jdbc connection string.

I aware that I need to `dbutils.secrets.setToken` to set a privileged secret token to be able to call secrets.get.

I have followed error message and successfully generated a token and the program just works. As the token only last for 48hrs, today it expired. I used same command to regenerate the token again in the notebook and copy & pasted to my local python program and updated value in the `dbutils.secrets.setToken`.

However, when I restart the program again, I still receive this error:

```
An error occurred while calling o23.get. :
java.lang.SecurityException: Accessing a secret from Databricks
Connect requires a privileged secrets token. To obtain such a token,
you can run the following in a Databricks workspace notebook:

displayHTML(   "&lt;b&gt;Privileged DBUtils token (expires in 48 hours):
</b>" +  
dbutils.notebook.getContext.apiToken.get.split("").mkString("&lt;span/&gt;"))

Then, run dbutils.secrets.setToken(<value>) locally to save the token.
Note that these tokens expire after **48 hours**.
```

I suspect if there is any local cache still holds the old value of the token? I have restarted cluster, seems no effect.

Is there anyone has the same issue? Or I have missed something?

Comment: Same problem here :-(
I tried putting this into the notebook:
`ctx = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext();
token = ctx.apiToken().get();
print(*token);`

but later this doesn't work:
`dbutils.secrets.setToken(token)`
throwing:
`AttributeError: 'SecretsHandler' object has no attribute 'setToken'`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by a DataBricks job which was in PROD workspace but it was trying to reach to UAT secret-vault / UAT database. After moving the job to UAT workspace it worked fine.